# Why is capital gains tax on inherited stocks calculated based on the value of the stock when inherited?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, inheritance

Here in the US, my understanding is that if you inherit a stock, then eventually sell the stock, the capital gains tax is calculated as if you had bought the stock at the price that would have been its fair market value on the day you inherited it.

Assuming I'm understanding this correctly (and please correct me if I'm wrong), what would be the reason for this? It seems like an illogical and unfair tax advantage for the person inheriting the stock.

Is this just some kind of political deal that was made because of constituents' negative emotions about the so-called "death tax?" Or is there some kind of rational justification that I'm not understanding that is based on sound principles of economics or accounting?

Comment: Beneficiaries never have to pay "death taxes" on the inheritances they receive: estate taxes  (if any) are paid by the estate, and could reduce the size of the inheritances that the beneficiaries receive.

Comment: _If_ the US is the same as (or close enough to) the UK in this respect, then my understanding is that _all_ inherited assets (not just shares) have their basis set at the time of death (not when you "receive" the assets). I would guess the idea is that the person who died didn't benefit from any capital gain that might have been made since _they_ bought the assets, and so no tax is due. For the inheritor, it seems fair that all that matters is the "present value" of what they inherit (_they_ don't "get more" because the original owner bought it for a song).

Comment: Rich people write the tax laws.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: The question is about capital gains taxes, not estate taxes.

Comment: _You_ are the one who brought up "death taxes".  If the inherited stock gets the original basis, then when the beneficiary sells the stock, there is typically a _huge_ capital gain on which the beneficiary gets to pay capital gains tax.  If the inherited stock gets the stepped-up basis, the beneficiary gets to pay capital gains tax only on the increase in value between the date of death and the sale.  Which would _you_ prefer as the beneficiary? With the step-up, the _estate_ pays estate tax (but often no tax because of the $5M+ exemption) on the increase during the lifetime of the deceased.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I brought up the concept of "death taxes" to speculate on possible irrational drivers of opinion among of voters and politicians. *Which would you prefer as the beneficiary?* My question is not asking what an individual beneficiary would rationally prefer. My question is asking whether this public policy has a rational basis in generally accepted principles of economics or accounting.

Comment: Ben, the wealthy save up their money, and buy a congressman who pays them back by writing tax code to save their donors at least 10x what they paid to buy them. See Koch brothers and Paul Ryan, for an example of such economics in action.

Comment: I vote to close this question on the grounds that it is unclear what is being asked, A secondary reason is that the answers to "What is the reason for this?" will primarily be opinion-based and not factual. The simple answer is that the reason that it is so is because that is the law. Congressional intent might be inferred to some extent from the historical record but that is a matter for the courts to settle, not random postings on this forum, and it is clear that the OP will not be satisfied with anything less than a definitive answer citing chapter and verse as to the "official reason".

Comment: I have been trying to be get involved with this forum, but I tell you what's unwelcoming is the fact that the majority of questions I come across are 'voted to close'.

Comment: The tax basis is reset at death because tax is assessed at death. Is that the sort of answer you were looking for?

Comment: @pfinnigan - This board is not like most. It's not meant for discussion, just Q&A. And we have a (hopefully) tight description of what's on topic. There are a number of reasons questions are closed. Most closed questions can be reopened with clarification and/or decent editing. Many cannot. You've asked 4 questions, one has been closed, the other, on hold. We are up to 21K questions, most of which remain open. Under 1600 closed, less than 10% and lower than other stack sites here.

Answer (score 4):

You just inherited a stock.  How much did the person who bought it pay for it?  How would you know?  But it's easy to determine how much the stock costs the day of the inheritance.  It's a definite day that can be recovered from public records and allows specific rules to determine which price on that day.  But you almost certainly don't know when the decedent purchased the stock much less the price that they paid for it.

If they don't mark to market, then everyone would be stuck trying to figure out how much their loved ones, who just died, paid for a stock.  So on what may be one of the worst days of their lives, they have to try to drag through all the paperwork to try to find the price paid for a stock that was bought at some prior time so that they can perpetuate that information for some time, possibly years away, when they need it.  And of course, they have to know that they will need the information.

Or a simpler way to look at it is that the one who inherited it has only seen a gain since the inheritance.  Why would they pay tax on gains from before they obtained the stock?  It would make more sense to charge the estate the tax on capital gains before that.  They have as much of the information as possible then.

While it's easy to view any tax break as applying more to the rich, it's worth noting that the people who would have the most trouble finding these records are the middle class (it seems unlikely that the poor have many stocks, although they may have wealthier relatives).  The rich, who can afford to pay people to keep their paperwork for them, are impacted less by arbitrary requirements.  Their employees keep track of that for them, particularly immediately after a loss.

The middle class are far more likely to try to do their own paperwork.  And because they've never done it previously, they tend to make mistakes and miss things.

Comment: +1, but remember, no middle class person is going to be subject to..... wait for it........ The...... Estate...... Tax!!! Only because $11M is at least a few thousand dollars more than middle class.

Comment: And this too is not an answer to "Why is capital gains tax on inherited stocks calculated based on the value of the stocks when inherited?" To which the only answer is that is what the law allows. For those like the OP who are distressed that beneficiaries are getting a break not available to ordinary people, the IRS is happy to accept the entire sale price as the capital gain (effectively, basis is 0) if the original purchase price is unknown, and there is no law prohibiting the OP from following this practice if and when he inherits some stock.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  But middle class people are still subject to the capital gains tax on inherited property.  What are you trying to say?  It doesn't seem to have any relationship to the question or this answer.

Comment: @Brythan - I see your point. But the basis is bumped up to the date of the inheritance. Due to the Estate Tax portion of our tax code.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  From the question:  "Or is there some kind of rational justification that I'm not understanding that is based on sound principles of economics or accounting?"  That's what I'm answering.  The rationale behind the stepped-up basis.

Comment: In the past difficulty of finding or reconstructing records was a strong reason, but for nearly all securities (or lots) purchased **since 2012 the broker is now required to track basis for you**, and report it on 1099B when sold or disposed; even if you move from one broker to another they are required to transfer the basis information between them. Today many people presumably still have 'uncovered' holdings from before 2012, but over time as older people die and younger people invest this fraction will decrease.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  Sure.  Two things.  First, the stepped-up basis law predates 2012.  Second, we go again to the problem of this being a horrid experience for people who actually experience it, however rare it may eventually become.  Get back to me in 2060 or so when people who bought stocks in their twenties in 2011 start dying.  And again, that would still lean towards a situation where the capital gain was taxed on the estate at inheritance.  Otherwise that unknown original basis from 2011 or earlier can propagate through multiple inheritances.

Answer (score 3):

The reason? As Pete noted, "Rich people write the tax code."

One can (and they do) argue about every bit of our tax structure. I live in a town where about 2/3 of our property tax goes to the school system. Zero kids, 1 kid, or 4, the property tax doesn't change. Fair? With my child off to college, I can move, or stay.

The tax code changes a bit over time. For estate tax, as far back as I recall, estates below the exemption amount (for 2018, $11.2M/person, up from $625K in 1998, when it first concerned me) benefit from no tax, and from the stepped up basis. The one exception was 2010, (when, as a Klingon would say "this is a good time to die) the tax itself was repealed, but there was no step up in basis. For the rich, this created an immediate windfall, but a paperwork burden for heirs that would extend until the asset was sold, or their own death.

The step-up is only one aspect of the estate tax discussion, it's not the only thing. Last year, at a $5.49M/person, fewer than 1 in 500 estates had any tax due at all. The doubling of the exemption makes it apply to far fewer.

It's fair to say that only the very rich would pay the tax, and of course only the even richer benefit from the cut, the increased exemption.

Comment: Your answer seems to be about estate taxes, but the question was about capital gains...?

Comment: They are inextricably linked. If another member can discuss the cap gain aspect while not mentioning estate tax, I will tip my hat to him/her.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are they linked? Estate taxes seem to me to be totally unrelated to capital gains tax.

Comment: Well, because you asked about the cap gain that’s avoided when one dies. And the lines of code that offer a stepped up basis to one’s estate is contained in the same section as the rest of the tax treatment for estates. Of dead people. Linked. Cap gain taxes on the undead are unrelated to estate tax, but once dead, they (cap gain and estate taxes) are related.

Comment: I'm baffled by your comment. -1 on this answer, which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: No idea what you are looking for. I sincerely hope another member can answer to your satisfaction. And intelligently answer a question containing the word “inherit” without mentioning estate tax.

Comment: A +1 to this answer to offset the -1 from the OP, and a close vote on the question on the grounds that it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: The question is about the stepped-up basis, but only two sentences in this "answer" mention the stepped-up basis.  Admittedly one of those sentences explains the problem quite well (the paperwork burden of a stepped-up basis is lower on non-rich people than an original basis standard would be).  But that refutes the rest of the answer, which claims that the stepped-up basis is primarily a benefit for the rich.  While I tend to agree that estate tax is relevant, it's not the primary concern here.